JSON formatting not working in SharePoint list calendar view
I am trying to change colors of calendar bar in calendar view of SharePoint Online list but that is not working for choice fields. I have one field named "names" but it is not working with that and working fine with other Text fields.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/calendar-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalEventClass": "=if([$names] == 'Choice 1', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGold', if([$names] == 'choice 2', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgPeach', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-defaultBackground'))"
}


I want this code to work with list calendar view formatting in SharePoint

Your JSON doesn't seem to have any problems, probably [$names] is wrong, please confirm what the value of this field is, please note that the case is sensitive and the spaces should be consistent.

In that view's settings, ensure that Choice column is checked off. Then on the calendar view, you can format the view and that choice column should then be visible as an option, and you can color code from there. If you want a color that isn't in the default options, select anything and then you can edit the JSON to be any other color using proper color code: https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/
